# Responsive webpage weird glitch with max-width

Tags: html, css

I have my webpage resize itself using "@media screen" and it works perfectly. It's setup to if the page reaches a certain width, it'll shrink the content to fit the page. However, there's this weird glitch that happens with my "hr" and "main p"
At roughly 800px the hr and p both extend past its container, I don't want that to happen. Here's the link( https://jsfiddle.net/3oezsrj6/1/ ) and here's my code. To see what I'm talking about, drag the width of the page and make it smaller and watch the content resize, but then at a certain point, on the right the content will spill out the container.

```
main{
    width: 960px;
    min-width: 320px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 3px;
}
footer{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: #333;
}
hr{
    border: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
}
main p{
    font-size: 15pt;
    width: 700px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 50px;
    margin: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 959px){
    main{
        width: 95%;
    }
    footer{
        width: 95%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 699px){
    hr{
        width: 90%;
    }
    main p{
        width: 90%;
    }
}

<main>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries
    </p>
</main>
<footer>
    <p>Yeet</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your container is actually `700px` wide with `15px margin` on either side and 
2x `3px` wide borders. This makes the width closer to `736px` and your media query needs to reflect that size and not the width of the container.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 737px){ }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of fixed width you have given for your p and hr. Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3oezsrj6/5/

The changes I made is :

```
hr{
    border: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}
main p{
    font-size: 15pt;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 50px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

You can change the width as per your requirements in percentage not in pixels as that will fix its width and hence not be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Update below CSS and you're done...

```
hr{
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
}
main p{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding; 0;
  text-align: center;
}
body{
  background-color: gray;
}
main{
    width: 960px;
    min-width: 320px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 3px;
}
footer{
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: #333;
}
hr{
    border: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    max-width: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
main p{
    font-size: 15pt;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-indent: 50px;
    margin: auto;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 959px){
    main{
        width: 95%;
    }
    footer{
        width: 95%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 699px){
    hr{
        width: 90%;
    }
    main p{
        width: 90%;
    }
}
```

```html
<main>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries
    </p>
</main>
<footer>
    <p>Yeet</p>
</footer>
```